# various errors in c++ linked list merge sort

Tags: c++

Hi I have an error in my linked list program and it is suppose to do merge sort on linked list.

I did declared it but it still giving me the error.

p.s. i didn't finish the merge sort function, but merge is suppose to compile already.

please help!!

Code:

```
#ifndef _NODE
#define _NODE 

template<typename ItemType>

class Node {
    private:
        ItemType item; // A data item
        Node<ItemType>* next; // Pointer to next node
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const ItemType& anItem);
        Node(const ItemType& anItem, Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
        void setItem(const ItemType& anItem);
        void setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
        void mergeSort(Node<ItemType>*& head);
        Node<ItemType>* merge(Node<ItemType>*& head1, Node<ItemType>*& head2);
        ItemType getItem() const;
        Node<ItemType>* getNext() const;
}; // end Node 

#endif

template<typename ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node() {

    next(nullptr)

} // end default constructor 

template<typename ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem) {

    item(anItem);
    next(nullptr);

} // end constructor 

template<typename ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem, Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr) {

    item(anItem);
    next(nextNodePtr);

} // end constructor 

template<typename ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::setItem(const ItemType& anItem) {

    item = anItem;

} // end setItem 

template<typename ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr) {

    next = nextNodePtr;

} // end setNext 

template<typename ItemType>
ItemType Node<ItemType>::getItem() const {

    return item;

} // end getItem 

template<typename ItemType>

Node<ItemType>* Node<ItemType>::getNext() const {

    return next;

} // end getNext

template<typename ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::mergeSort(Node<ItemType>*& head) {

    Node<ItemType>*countptr = head;
    int length = 0;

    while (countptr->getNext() != nullptr) {
        length++;
        countptr = countptr->getNext();
    }

    //if only one or non in list then return list
    if (length <= 1)
        return head;

    //int half = length / 2;





}

template<typename ItemType>
ItemType Node<ItemType>::merge(Node<ItemType>*& head1, Node<ItemType>*& head2) {

    Node<ItemType>*head = nullptr;
    Node<ItemType>*cur = nullptr;

    //set the first element
    if (head1->getItem() >= head2->getItem()) {
        head = head2;
        head2 = head2->getNext();
    }
    else {
        head = head1;
        head1 = head1->getNext();
    }

    cur = head;

    while (true) {
        if (head1->getItem() == NULL && head2->getItem() != NULL) {
            cur->setNext(head2);
            cur = cur->getNext();
            head2 = head2->getNext();
        }
        else if (head2->getItem() == NULL && head1->getItem() != NULL) {
            cur->setNext(head1);
            cur = cur->getNext();
            head1 = head1->getNext();
        }
        else if (head1->getItem() >= head2->getItem()) {
            cur->setNext(head2);
            cur = cur->getNext();
            head2 = head2->getNext();
        }
        else if (head1->getItem() <= head2->getItem()) {
            cur->setNext(head1);
            cur = cur->getNext();
            head1 = head1->getNext();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }


    return head;
}
```

and here is my error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE

\xlocale(341): war
ning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
c:\users\mykev\desktop\Node.h(145): error C2244: 'Node<ItemType>::merge': unable
 to match function definition to an existing declaration
c:\users\mykev\desktop\Node.h(100): note: see declaration of 'Node<ItemType>::me
rge'
c:\users\mykev\desktop\Node.h(145): note: definition
c:\users\mykev\desktop\Node.h(145): note: 'ItemType Node<ItemType>::merge(Node<I
temType> *&,Node<ItemType> *&)'
c:\users\mykev\desktop\Node.h(145): note: existing declarations
c:\users\mykev\desktop\Node.h(145): note: 'Node<ItemType> *Node<ItemType>::merge
(Node<ItemType> *&,Node<ItemType> *&)'
```

Comment: Defined: `ItemType Node<ItemType>::merge(Node<ItemType>*& head1, Node<ItemType>*& head2` declared: `Node<ItemType>* merge(Node<ItemType>*& head1, Node<ItemType>*& head2);` do you see the obvious difference in the return type?

Comment: OMG!!! the pointers...yes!! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've (at least) two issues in your code

1) your default constructor is missing a semi-colon around line 29

2) your prototype for merge (around line 17) doesn't look like your implementation (around line 100). You could change the line 100 to look more like:

```
template<typename ItemType>
Node<ItemType>* Node<ItemType>::merge(Node<ItemType>*& head1, Node<ItemType>*& head2) {
```

Comment: thank you!! I fixed number 1 and 2!! thank you so much. haven't slept for a day really makes you unproductive.

Comment: np - but that's what the compiler's for! also, make your own life easier, and use nullptr everywhere (instead of some of those NULLs you've got floating around)